# Can't locate id elements with Python3 and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get all 'id' elements in a certain web page. I can find the ul element that contains them, and I can even find a specific element by id (i.e. browser.find_element_by_id('380797')), but when I'm executing browser.find_all_elements_by_tag_name('id') the result is an empty list. I also tried by css or xpath, same result.

How can I get all id elements in the list? 
The html looks something like that:

...
        ...
        ...
[image]

Comment: Specifically about ID, it might be dynamic and change each time the page is rendered. Another thing to check is whether the section of the page you are working with is inside an iframe. If it is, you must switch to it first.

Comment: Thank you @EugeneS. I'm having some trouble figuring out whether this part is inside an iframe, what is the best way to do that? Also, if it is inside an iframe, how come I can locate a specific id element but not all id elements?

Comment: tag_name refers to the name of the tag. For example div in <div>, or ul in <ul>. So the reason your select didn't work is because the tag is not called id (the attribute is).

Answer (score 1):

You may use execute_script. (better way in my opinion)

```
external_js = """
    jsonData = [];
    data = document.querySelectorAll("#placards-container > ul")[0];

    for(var row of data["children"]){
        JSON.stringify(jsonData.push({id : row.id}));
    }
    return jsonData;
"""
browser.execute_script(external_js)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id="placards-container"]/ul/div[contains(@class,'placard')]
```

The `contains()` method is the best approach for detecting the exact type of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use general attributes that are present in all the elements.
The rule is: find all div's with id's from the div with placards-container id.

CSS:
`browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("#placards-container div[id]")` or
`browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("#placards-container ul>div[id]")`

Xpath:
`browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='placards-container']//div[@id]")` or
`browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='placards-container']/ul/div[@id]")`